# How to get data from Firebase Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase

See this is my HTML File:

```
<div class="container m-3 p-3">
 <h1>Current Items</h1>
 <ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">An item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">A fourth item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">And a fifth one</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

And this is my TS file:

```
import ...

@Component ...
export class HomeComponent ..

  // get every data from cloud firestore from the collection 'data' and return it as a string
  getData() {
   const db = getFirestore();
  }

  ...

}
```

And inside getData(), I want to return the data from my collection "data" in Firebase Firestore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to add your firebase config into environment.ts file like shown below:-

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebaseConfig : {
    apiKey: "*************************",
    authDomain: "*************************",
    projectId: "*************************",
    storageBucket: "*************************",
    messagingSenderId: "*************************",
    appId: "*************************",
    measurementId: "*************************"
  }
};
```

and then import `AngularFireModule` and `AngularFirestoreModule` from `@angular/fire`

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
AngularFirestoreModule
```

then in you service class:-

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';

constructor(private fbs: AngularFirestore) {}

  getData() {
   return this.fbs
  .collection("collectionName")
  .snapshotChanges();
}
```

Comment: It's giving me errors, the first error is `Unable to evaluate this expression statically.` and the second error is `Unknown reference.`